# Implementation of a database with multiple users that can access different sections

Tags: database

I am trying to figure out the best way to implement a database system such as mysql or access or what ever everyone suggests that will make it easy for me to do these specific things:

1) Have multiple users updating the database
2) Users will have different permissions to view the different tables in the database

At this period in time we have multiple excel spreadsheets keeping track of finances from different revenue streams. with different classifications. Then we have a spreadsheet that is somewhat a master spreadsheet that adds up the other 2-3 spreadsheets.

Ideally, User A and B can only view/update Table 1    ::
         User C and D can only view/update Table 2 ::
         Admin can only view/update Table 3 ( table 3 updates by adding specific columns from table 1 and table 2)

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction to what platform and features I should read up on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy just "GRANT" or "REVOKE" UPDATE and SELECT privileges as required.

Slight differences depending on the database you are using. Most support this but ACCESS, SQLITE, and, other lightweight databases dont support this construct or only partially support this.